# Make a responsive stepper with 24 steps using Angular material? Is there any alternate responsive stepper option for the same?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, responsive

How to make a 24 steps stepper responsive using Angular material? Is there any alternate responsive stepper option to achieve the same?

I have tried container-fluid but nothing works after a certain point I can view only 6 steps on small screen.

I have used below [StackBlitz to create the MatStepper](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-stepper-with-component-steps-hnzrnm?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html).

This a sample code what if I need 28 steps and how to make in responsive on small screen?

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper class="container-fluid" style="width: 100%;">
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <span>Name</span>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
    <p>You are now done.</p>
    <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</mat-step>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my english is too bad , i come to you again to see if you resolved your problem ?
i tried my solution verticaly and horizontaly and i gave more than 10 sections
and i thinked about it , why you dont do a menu bar ? like this :

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">

  <button mat-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>

  <mat-menu x-position="before" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item  routerLink="/1">1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/2">2</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/3">3</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/4"> 4</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/5">5 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/6"> 6 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/7"> 7 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/8"> 8</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/9"> 9 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/10">10 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/11"> 11 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/12"> 12 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/13"> 13 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/14"> 14 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/15"> 15 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/16">  16 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/17"> 17 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/18">18 </button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/19">19</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/20">20 Croisé</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/21">21</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/22">2</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/23">23</button>
    <!--<button mat-menu-item>Help</button>-->
  </mat-menu>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

you just have to organise your rooting and you can have same fonctionality ?

Answer (score 1):

add your steps in html

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>something</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="thirdCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
```

........

and add in your .ts the list of steps:

```
firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  thirdFormGroup: FormGroup;
  forthFormGroup: FormGroup;
  cinqFormGroup: FormGroup;
  sixFormGroup: FormGroup;
  septFormGroup: FormGroup;
  huitFormGroup: FormGroup;
```

......

add the list of action and ctrl in ngOInnit like this:

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      thirdCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.forthFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      forthreCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.cinqFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      cinqCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

.......

and it will work